# Provide() reactive Pinia properties to child components

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

### Goal

Is it possible to `provide` a Pinia store property while preserving its reactivity in the children? I've tried wrapping it with `computed` and `function`. I'm leaning away from props on this one to reduce prop drilling.

Using `dispatchStore` directly in each child is an option, but I am hoping to centralize things a bit.

### Target Code

```js
import { DivisionsProvider } from '../symbols'
const dispatchStore = useDispatchStore()

provide(DivisionsProvider, {
    jobsData,
    // Loses reactivity in child
    selectedDivisionId: dispatchStore.selectedDivisionId,
    // Loses reactivity in child
    selectedDivisionStatus: dispatchStore.selectedDivisionStatus,
    onSelectDivisionId,
    onSelectDivisionStatus,
    getStatusesWithJobCounts
})
```

### Environment

- `pinia: ^2.0.32`
- `vue: ^3.4.15`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `toRef()`:

```
import {toRef} from 'vue';
import { DivisionsProvider } from '../symbols'
const dispatchStore = useDispatchStore()

provide(DivisionsProvider, {
    jobsData,
    // Loses reactivity in child
    selectedDivisionId: toRef(dispatchStore, 'selectedDivisionId'),
    // Loses reactivity in child
    selectedDivisionStatus: toRef(dispatchStore, 'selectedDivisionStatus'),
    onSelectDivisionId,
    onSelectDivisionStatus,
    getStatusesWithJobCounts
});
```

But I would prefer a getter/setter:

```
import { DivisionsProvider } from '../symbols'
const dispatchStore = useDispatchStore()

provide(DivisionsProvider, {
    jobsData,
    // Loses reactivity in child
    get selectedDivisionId(){
      return dispatchStore.selectedDivisionId;
    }
    set selectedDivisionId(val){
      dispatchStore.selectedDivisionId = val
    }
    // Loses reactivity in child
    get selectedDivisionStatus(){
      return dispatchStore.selectedDivisionStatus;
    }
    set selectedDivisionStatus(val){
      dispatchStore.selectedDivisionStatus= val
    }
    onSelectDivisionId,
    onSelectDivisionStatus,
    getStatusesWithJobCounts
})
```

As you see it's a pattern so I would have a utility:

```
import { DivisionsProvider } from '../symbols'
const dispatchStore = useDispatchStore()

provide(DivisionsProvider,
    // implement yourself with Object.defineProperty
    reactiveCopy({
    jobsData,
    onSelectDivisionId,
    onSelectDivisionStatus,
    getStatusesWithJobCounts
  }, dispatchStore, 'selectedDivisionId', 'selectedDivisionId')
)
```